# Navigate in Detailpages without using the master

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am using a home page in a masterdetailpage (as the detail).
The home page should let the user access to the other detail pages without passing through the master page.(when clicking some buttons)

How to do it? I think Navigation.PushAsync() doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the master page using the MainPage property of your App class.
An example to navigate to a specifi Detail Page:

```
(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new Page1();
```